# How to run npm tests from a single folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, chai

Currently I am testing a React node application, and have all my tests in the root/tests folder, with components in separate folders pertaining to their function.

I have 10+ folders and 100+ tests, and would like to 'watch' a single folder while I write a test for a new component.

Currently, I am using

> npm run test:watch

Which is working brilliantly, however, not only is there a lot of overhead re-running the 100 other tests not related to my new component, it's also hard to weed through all the feedback to see the results of my current test.

Is there a nice command to only watch the directory of my new test, or even the test file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass mocha test directory to the npm command:

```
npm run test:watch -- root/tests/subfolder
```

However it might depend on how your test script `test:watch` is defined.

Comment: Thanks @madox2, it still seemed to run everything, my test:watch is defined as `"test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch --watch-extensions js,jsx"`

Comment: `"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js \"test/**/*@(.js|.jsx)\"",`

Comment: @MarkKadlec When you want to pass directory to the command line you must not specify it in npm script. You can create new script e.g. `"test:watch:sub": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --watch --watch-extensions js,jsx"` and then pass the directory to the command `npm run test:watch:sub -- root/tests/subfolder`